# Dropbox Sync iOS SDK download last image

Tags: ios, synchronization, dropbox-api

I have trouble downloading the last image in Dropbox, basically the image is refreshed until I change it for a new one, like this:

Run App -> Show the last image -> Change image1 on other device -> No change -> Change image(2) again on other device -> Add image 1 -> Change image(3) again on other device -> Add image 2, etc..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    DBFilesystem* filesystem = [DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem];
    PicturePath = [[DBPath root] childPath:@"image.jpeg"];

    [filesystem addObserver:self forPathAndChildren:PicturePath block:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                  [self ActualizarFoto];
        });
    }]; 
}

-(void)ActualizarFoto{
    [DropboxPicture close];

    DropboxPicture = [[DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem] openFile:PicturePath error:nil];
    NSData *ImagenDropbox = [DropboxPicture readData:nil];
    imagenView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:ImagenDropbox];

}
```

How I can download the latest synchronized image Dropbox and not the previous one?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How I can download the latest synchronized image dropbox and not the previous one?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem/question. Do you mean you're seeing old versions of the image, when you're expecting to see newer versions? If so, that's likely because you're getting older cached data when you read the `DBFile`. You need to hold open the `DBFile` and add an observer to it itself to wait for the new version to available, and then update to it and read it: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/ios#observers